# How to make bixby interactive with user?

Tags: android, bixby

I am developing an app on samsung bixby and I want to make it interactive but unable to understand how to start. Have refer their document and is referring this link

> https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/refining-dialog.intro-dialog

but not able to understand how to start.

The whole idea of mine is evaluate as

User: Hi bixby, what is the capital of India?
Bixby: Delhi is the capital of India. Do you want me to list down other famous city of India?
User: Yes, please list down.
Bixby: Mumbai, Delhi, Bangalore and many more city. Do you want to know more about Mumbai Or delhi?
User:.............

Have taken the user input through action file and have processed into js and i am able to show the result. But I am unable to make it interactive as per the example. Please help.

Comment: Check this link, might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069385/interactive-conversation-implementation-in-bixby/57075002?noredirect=1#comment100675845_57075002

Answer (score 2):

The Bixby Developer Program is Live now. So please goto Bixby Developers to check out the latest developments. You can download for both windows as well as mac operating systems.

The latest releases for the 4th quarter for Bixby can be seen here - [Bixby Studio Release](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/release-notes/bixby-studio.2018-Q4-Bixby-Studio-Release-Notes)

The following link to the Bixby guide will help you solve the queries of understanding the transitioning  process from one dialogue to another and further serialising the process -
[Bixby Guide](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers)

Answer (score -2):

At the moment, we are still in Private Beta so we cannot answer this question publicly but we will share an answer as soon as the IDE is released in a few weeks. Until then we request that you post your questions in the channels recommended for Private Beta participants.

Best,
Shan

Comment: This answer does not help the OP.