# Interactive conversation implementation in Bixby

Tags: bixby

**I am new to Bixby, facing trouble in Interactive conversation implementation.
Something like below :**

User: "Hi Bixby, book me a table at Flemings Steakhouse."

Okay, for what day?

User: "Tomorrow."

Okay, for what time?

User: "6:00pm."

Okay, for how many people?

User: "Four."

Okay, booking a table for 4 people at Flemings Steakhouse tomorrow at 6:00pm.

**If any suggestion , please help.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't too hard with Bixby.  What you'll want to do is create an action that will collect all the input from the user.  It could look similar to this

**Your action**

```
action (BookReservaton) {
  type(Search)
  description (Book a reservation)
  collect {

    // Ask for the user's reservation date
    input (reservationDate) {
      type (time.DateTimeExpression)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }

    // Prompt for number of guests, but also allow them to confirm 2
    input (numberOfGuests) {
      type (NumberOfGuests)
      min (Required) max (One)
      default-init {
        intent {
          goal: NumberOfGuests
          value: NumberOfGuest(2)
        }
      }
      prompt-behavior (AlwaysSelection)
    } 
  }
  output (Reservation)
}
```

In your case, you're going to need to collect input from the user when they don't provide your required input from their utterance.  [This](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/sample-capsules/samples/input-forms) is a good example of collecting dates, etc.  You can also support someone saying 'Book a table for 4 this Tuesday at 7PM' without needing to prompt them for input.  Bixby will only prompt the user when it doesn't have a required input.

Comment: How the prompt is coming to recieve input data (for user interaction ; saving input data and continuing next question) ? Is it by training or any prompt syntax there ; like you used for the second input

Comment: You might want to investigate 'at prompt for' in your NL training.   You can refer to this https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/training.intro-training.

Comment: Thats Awesome :)